# How to get Activity logs from Azure Portal

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk-.net

I would like to retrieve all activity logs from Azure Portal. I started by trying with connections. I actually get my connections but I don't know how to get the related activity logs. Am I using the right API ?

```
var operation = networkClient.VirtualNetworkGatewayConnections.ListWithHttpMessagesAsync(resourceGroup);
if (operation != null)
{
    var result = operation.Result;

    if (result != null)
    {
         var body = result.Body;

         foreach (Microsoft.Azure.Management.Network.Models.VirtualNetworkGatewayConnection connection in body)
         {
              Console.WriteLine(connection.Name);
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this sample code with little modifications : 
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Analyze-Azure-Audit-Logs-0977ada4

```
InsightsClient client = new InsightsClient(credentials);
DateTime endDateTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime startDateTime = endDateTime.AddDays(days);
string filterString = FilterString.Generate<ListEventsForResourceProviderParameters>(eventData => (eventData.EventTimestamp >= startDateTime) && (eventData.EventTimestamp <= endDateTime) && (eventData.ResourceType == "Microsoft.Network/connections"));

EventDataListResponse response = client.EventOperations.ListEvents(filterString, selectedProperties: null);
List<EventData> logList = new List<EventData>(response.EventDataCollection.Value);

while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.EventDataCollection.NextLink))
{
    response = client.EventOperations.ListEventsNext(response.EventDataCollection.NextLink);
    logList.AddRange(response.EventDataCollection.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure Activity logs / Audit logs can be read in multiple ways. You can export them to a storage account and view it from there.  You can use webhooks and rest api to read it using custom tools or third party tools. You can use them as datasource to powerbi and view it as charts, tables etc. You can add log analytics solutions to your workspace and configure it to read activity logs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-activity-logs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-add-solutions

Answer (score 0):

> how to get the related activity logs

If you’d like to programmatically retrieve and view activity logs, you could try to [use the Azure Monitor REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-rest-api-walkthrough#retrieve-activity-log-data).

[image]

Comment: So, I can't use Microsoft.Azure.Management nor Microsoft.Azure.Insights NuGet packages ?
I have to manage several portals as each of my clients have its own portal so I try to keep it very simple.
I'm not familiar to REST but if it's the only way, I'm going to use it, thanks.